# Combo box issues in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, combobox, extjs4.1

I'm using Sencha 4.1.2a, IE 9.

I'm in the process on migrating my company's project from sencha 4.07 to sencha 4.1.2.

I'm now face with unexpected problems with combo box. We have extend the combo box in order to respond to our needs.

First they are really slow, but only on IE (Currently using 9, but changing browser mode doesn't seem to have any effect...). I can't recreate this issue in both Chrome and FF.

Second, the first n items on the combo box appear ok, like this:

[image]

But soon as i scroll down this happens:

[image]

And only when i hover above the items, do the items "return" to their position. But only the ones rendered in the first place, since the other items bellow are never render. And then i end up with this:

[image]

I thought this was related to some changes made in the newest version of sencha (that meant changing our own code), but the fact that it runs ok in the other 2 browsers seems to point to the fact that the problem is with IE...

Any thoughts on why this happen?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I found out the problem.

It's the css class 'x-boundlist-item' which has css3 properties.

My question now is how to prevent/disable sencha from using CSS3 (if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Check this thread http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?205867